# How can I see the main window designer with all controls the same it looks like when running the program?

Tags: wpf

This is before running the program:

[image: Main window]

This is after running the program, This is what I want to see in the designer:

[image: When running]

The problem is that in the designer I don't see all the controls buttons.
Not the same when it's running. If I want to add a new button or any control I can't see in the designer where to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have an expander. Set `IsExpanded` to `true` and you will see the content, don't forget to turn it to your desired value before running :)

Comment: Where do I set the IsExpanded to true ? Where is it in the designer ?

Comment: In your first picture, at the bottom left you can see `Design` tab and `XAML` tab. Click on `XAML` tab and try to find the expander. There, type `IsExpanded="True" ` . If you don't know how to find it, post your `XAML` code and I will help you.

Comment: Here is a link for the XAML code. I found one place with IsExpanded: <Expander Padding="5,0,0,0"
                  IsExpanded="{Binding Settings.UI.Expanded}"> And I'm not sure where to insert the IsExpanded="true"  https://pastebin.com/Hq6YqS26

Comment: Change `IsExpanded="{Binding Settings.UI.Expanded}">` to `"IsExpanded="True">` that way you will see all your controls there. Remember to change it back when you compile it ;)

Comment: @BenziAvrumi Remember if this helped you, upvote it and mark it as the answer :D